# Send Telemetry from more than one device to azure IoT hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to send telemetry data from two simulated devices using C#, I am using stream analytics to catch the input and pass it to Power BI as output. I am using two input streams and two output streams for the devices, Bothe the input streams have different consumer groups. Stream analytics job is able to catch only one input stream at a time, which goes into both the outputs.

Comment: I am not sure what your question actually is, but have you tried using multiplexing? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40227905/1051634

Comment: Are you using two separate instances of the DeviceClient, each with its device identity?

Comment: The scenario you described should work. Are you using the same serialization format for both the inputs? Also, are there any filters that may be filtering data out?